# Constructing the function for non linear least squares

Tags: integration, derivatives, summation, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose I have the following non linear-model:
$$
y=f(x ; \beta)+\varepsilon,
$$
where
$$
f(x ; \beta) =\sum_{j=0}^{p} w(\theta ; j)\cdot x_{j}.
$$

With the exponential Almon structure:
$$\omega_{j}\left(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2}\right)=\frac{\exp \left\{\theta_{1} j+\theta_{2} j^{2}\right\}}{\sum_{j=1}^{p} \exp \left\{\theta_{1} j+\theta_{2} j^{2}\right\}}.$$

I would like to obtain the normal equation

$$\boldsymbol{\Delta} \boldsymbol{\beta}=\left(\mathbf{J}^{\mathbf{T}} \mathbf{J}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{J}^{\mathbf{T}} \boldsymbol{\Delta} \mathbf{y}$$

In order to obtain the value of the parameters I need to construct J.
Where $$\mathrm{J}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta_{1}} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta_{2}} \\
\end{array}\right)$$

Does anyone know a way to rewrite the sum of the given exponential Almon structure such that I can obtain J more easily without the summation sign? One option is to work out the sum manually but this procedure gets time-consuming when p becomes large.

Wiki for nls: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares